# Image won't add to SQL database

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I have a HTML form where a user fills out a few details to register for a competition. I want them to be able to upload a photo. The PHP script successfully enters everything into the database except Photo Name and Photo, any ideas why?

HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="addboat.php">
  <p>Add your boat to the 2018 species hunt</p>

  <p>Boat Name :- <input type="text" name="boatname" size="42"></p>
  <p>Boat Make/Model :- <input type="text" name="boatmake" size="42"></p>
  <p>Skipper :- <input type="text" name="skipper"></p>
  <p>Photo:- <input type="file" name="file"></p>

   <input type="hidden" name="huntyear" value="2018">
  <p align="center"><input type="submit" value="Submit" name="B1"></p>
  <p align="center">&nbsp;</p>
</form>
```

PHP:

```
$huntyear = $_POST['huntyear'];
$boatname = $_POST['boatname'] ;
$boatmake = $_POST['boatmake'];
$skipper = $_POST['skipper'];

// Image add
$imagename=$_FILES["file"]["name"]; 

//Get the content of the image and then add slashes to it 
$imagetmp=addslashes (file_get_contents($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']));


$query_rsCatch = "INSERT INTO SpeciesHuntBoats (Year, BoatName, BoatMake, Skipper, PhotoName, Photo) VALUES

('$huntyear','$boatname','$boatmake','$skipper','$imagename','$imagetmp')";
$rsCatch = mysql_query($query_rsCatch, $webdb) or die(mysql_error());
```

[image]

Comment: Every time you use [the `mysql_`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)
 database extension in new code
 **[this happens](https://media.giphy.com/media/kg9t6wEQKV7u8/giphy.gif)**
 it is deprecated and has been for years and is gone for ever in PHP7.
If you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` or `mysqli` database extensions and prepared statements.
[Start here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: Your script is wide open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: If you run `addslashes` on an image you are going to change the file. Probably into a format that NO LONGER is a valid image file

Comment: If you must store the actual file in a table, run base64encode on it first. But it is a whole lot simpler to store the file on the filesystem and just keep the location in the database

Comment: Thank you, I will research the above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use multipart form-data in your form
`<form action="action_page" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

Comment: Thank you, worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

When you make a **`POST`** request, you need to encode the data that forms the body of the request HTML forms provides **`multipart/form-data`** is significantly more complicated but it allows entire files to be included in the data. **`enctype='multipart/form-data’`** is used when you want to upload a file **(images, text files etc.)** to the server.